# query from multiple tables with python or SQLite

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy

I have three numeric tables with different row number, for an example:

| tableA |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 8 |

| tableB |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 23 |
| 15 |
| 80 |

| tableC |
| --- |
| 500 |
| 200 |
| 180 |

And I want to find out something like:
A-B+C < 200

so the answer is

| answer |
| --- |
| 1,10,180 |
| 1,15,180 |
| 8,10,180 |

Is there any ways to do this?

`pandas.DataFrame.query` and `numpy.where` seems only work on single table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use cross join, so possible filter one final `DataFrame`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='cross').merge(df3, how='cross').query("tableA-tableB+tableC < 200")
print (df)
    tableA  tableB  tableC
1        1      10     200
2        1      10     180
4        1      23     200
5        1      23     180
7        1      15     200
8        1      15     180
10       1      80     200
11       1      80     180
13       8      10     200
14       8      10     180
16       8      23     200
17       8      23     180
19       8      15     200
20       8      15     180
22       8      80     200
23       8      80     180
```